# TCPDF Progress Bar

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, tcpdf

I am using php and TCPDF to generate a custom PDF file from several MySQL queries.  Once the user clicks the "Generate PDF" button a new tab opens and the PDF process starts.  It takes, on average, about 10 seconds to build the PDF.  Once the file is ready the browser closes the blank page and displays the save as dialog window.

I'd like to display some type of message to the user while the PDF is creating.  I am somewhat of a noob when it comes to AJAX/JQUERY, but have tried to implement several solutions without success.

Things to note:

1. The backend is Joomla!
2. Using `$pdf->Output('example.pdf','D')` to generate the pdf
3. Using ob_end_clean prior to `$pdf-Output` to avoid the "TCPDF: Data already output" error.

I have tried the method that adds a `<div>` to the end of my page as well as some jQuery/CSS that would show an animated gif while the page is loading.  It did not work, and I somehow get the feeling this is either caused by the ob_end_clean or the Joomla! framework.

Comment: I recommend just set your `Header('Content-disposition: attachment')` so that no window gets opened.  This way, the file will just be downloaded via the browser's normal file downloader, I believe.  Something like this: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');header('Content-type: application/pdf');`

Comment: I am sending the required info via POST to the new page.  I can not output the PDF on the same page because of the HTML/CSS formatting we are using in TCPDF.  It is very sensative so building the PDF on a clean page is preferred.  I also can not switch PDF classes either as it has taken quite a long time just to get this far with TCPDF.

Comment: I understand, I have worked with TCPDF, too.  If you want a progress bar you are going to have to send your POST data via AJAX.

Comment: So if I send the POST data via AJAX, the AJAX method I described earlier should work?

Comment: the ajax is using to receive data and change the progress bar value
at first you must handle the status of progress in server side

Comment: Actually, the AJAX thing won't completely work for you if you want to display the PDF in a new window.  You would have to create the AJAX request, show the loading graphic, save the PDF to a database, then render the link to retrieve the PDF from the database and hide the loading graphic.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

1) for progress bar you must run the script via ajax

2)you have pdf page count...on each page creating you can change progress bar value

3)you must use php output control function for each pages of pdf created
php have a list of good function for this

i dont see your code but you must do some thing like this

```
$i = 1;
while($i< PDF_PAGE_COUNT){
        ob_start();
        pdf_create_page($i);
        echo $i/PDF_PAGE_COUNT;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
$i++;
}
```

p.s : for better answer please paste your code here!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#PDF").click(function(){
  /*-------------- validate filters -------------------------------*/
  if(!(validarFecha(fecha_ymd(rj.Get('#TxtFechaIni').value())))){Warn2.show();return false; }
  if(!(validarFecha(fecha_ymd(rj.Get('#TxtFechaFin').value())))){Warn3.show();return false; } 
  if(Date.parse(fecha_ymd(rj.Get('#TxtFechaIni').value()))>=Date.parse(fecha_ymd(rj.Get('#TxtFechaFin').value()))){Warn.show();return false; }
 /* is alll right */ 
 else {  
    /* show a message while generating report*/
    WinSnd.Message({type:'info', title:'generating report', value:'Please, wait ...', buttons:' '}).show(); 
    /* url with params to send */
    var url="report.php?&slash="+'<?php echo(isset($_POST['slash'])?@$_POST['slash']:@$_GET['slash']);?>'+"&module="+'<?php echo (isset($_POST['module'])?@$_POST['module']:@$_GET['module']);?>'
    +"&TxtCheck=excel"
    +"&TxtFechaIni="+rj.Get('#TxtFechaIni').value()
    +"&TxtFechaFin="+rj.Get('#TxtFechaFin').value()
    +"&LkpTdoc="+rj.Get('#LkpTdoc').value();

    var filename = <?php echo '"'.$gSave.'"';?>; /* name for report, i set*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    
    xhr.onload = function(){
      WinSnd.hide(); /* hide message */
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response es un blob file
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.download = filename; // file name 
      a.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click(); // action
      delete a; //
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.send(); 
      
  }// fin validaciones
   
    });//fin function 
});// fin
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally not as informative as if they had some explanation as to how they answer the question.